# Using dlopen to get handle of libc memory allocation functions

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, dlopen

Can someone help me to know how can i use dlopen to get handle of libc memory allocation functions? Especially, something like searching the libc path and then taking the handle. What modes should be used to invoke dlsym?

Idea is:

1. Search libc path
2. Invoke dlopen on it
3. Use dlsym to access the memory functions (malloc, calloc etc) and
4. use the functions

Please help me with a code snippet of the above 4 steps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a code snippet, HTH

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// For LIBC_SO which expands to proper libc name
#include <gnu/lib-names.h>

int main()
{  
   void *handle; 
   
   // dlopen will search the path for you
   // LIBC_SO expands to shared library name
   // for libc
   handle = dlopen(LIBC_SO, RTLD_LAZY); 

   if(handle){
         void* (*mallocptr)(size_t);
         void (*freeptr)(void*);

         // Locate symbols
         *(void**)(&mallocptr) = dlsym(handle, "malloc");
         *(void**)(&freeptr) = dlsym(handle, "free");
         
         if(!mallocptr || !freeptr){
            printf("%s\n", dlerror());
            return 1;
         }

         // Allocate and use memory
         char *ptr = (*mallocptr)(4);
         ptr[0] = 'H'; ptr[1] = 'i'; ptr[2] = '\n'; ptr[3] = '\0';
         printf(ptr);
         
         // Free it
         (*freeptr)(ptr);
   }
   else{
      printf("%s\n", dlerror());
      return 1;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: -bash-3.2# ./a.out 

dlopen failed

Comment: Note that I'm using libc.so.6 in my code - if you're using a different version of libc, you have to change it. Have a look in your /lib folder, is there a file named libc.so.<something>?

Comment: I have libc.so.6, and i have exported it...don't know why still dlopen is failing.

Comment: I mean it is exported in LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: Weird, did you modify the code I posted? Is the message "dlopen failed" produced by dlerror?

Comment: No, the code is "as is" compiled. Just added header for stdlib. In native it is compiling fine, but in my target it is failing. Target is ARM. It has libc.so.6 in /devel/usr/lib, which i exported in LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Comment: is libc.so.6 in /devel/usr/lib on your machine or on the target device? try running your executable like this: env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/folder/containing/libc ./a.out

Comment: I tried the same...anyways your code is fine. I will try it out, may be some issues with our distro installation in target. Thank you.

Comment: This answer helped someone 10 years later as well. Thanks!

Comment: [RTM](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html).  There is no need to call `dlopen()` and pass the resulting handle to `dlsym()`.  `dlsym( RTLD_NEXT, "malloc" );` will find the "next occurrence" of `malloc()` "in the search order".

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but the question itself seems based on a false assumption that `dlopen()` must be used to locate objects in the system's standard `libc`.

There's no need to use `dlopen()` unless you are deliberately loading your functions from a specific shared object that's not the default `libc`.  As noted in the comments to the other answer, forcing a specific path for what should likely just be the default `libc` doesn't always work.  Because the default `libc` is almost certainly already loaded into your process's address space, and it doesn't have to be in the same location or even have the same name.

Just use `dlsym( RTLD_NEXT, "malloc" )` to find `malloc()`, for example.

Per [the Linux `dlsym()` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html):

> There are two special pseudo-handles that may be specified in handle:
>
> **RTLD_DEFAULT**
>
> Find the first occurrence of the desired symbol using the
> default shared object search order.  The search will
> include global symbols in the executable and its
> dependencies, as well as symbols in shared objects that
> were dynamically loaded with the RTLD_GLOBAL flag.
>
> **RTLD_NEXT**
>
> Find the next occurrence of the desired symbol in the
> search order after the current object.  This allows one to
> provide a wrapper around a function in another shared
> object, so that, for example, the definition of a function
> in a preloaded shared object (see LD_PRELOAD in ld.so(8))
> can find and invoke the "real" function provided in
> another shared object (or for that matter, the "next"
> definition of the function in cases where there are
> multiple layers of preloading).
>
> The `_GNU_SOURCE` feature test macro must be defined in order to
> obtain the definitions of `RTLD_DEFAULT` and `RTLD_NEXT` from
> `<dlfcn.h>.`

This is all that's necessary:

```
     void* (*mallocptr)(size_t);
     void (*freeptr)(void*);

     // Locate symbols
     mallocptr = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "malloc");
     freeptr = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "free");

     if(!mallocptr || !freeptr){
        printf("%s\n", dlerror());
        return 1;
     }

     // Allocate and use memory
     char *ptr = mallocptr(4);
     ptr[0] = 'H'; ptr[1] = 'i'; ptr[2] = '\n'; ptr[3] = '\0';
     printf(ptr);

     // Free it
     freeptr(ptr);
```

Note that I removed the `*(void**)(&mallocptr)` casts - those are not needed.  If `gcc` *incorrectly* complains about the assignment (`gcc` will improperly issue warnings when assigning `void *` pointers but the C standard specifies that a `void *` pointer can be safely assigned to any pointer...),

Comment: Can this be used to find local symbols in shared objects? Or will it only find global ones?

Comment: @SRobertJames Maybe - it depends on how the shared object was built and linked, and if the shared object [has been stripped](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/strip.html).  On Linux, you might see a significant difference in the output from `nm -D libXXX.so` and `nm -a libXXX.so`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435352/limiting-visibility-of-symbols-when-linking-shared-libraries