# How to strip symbols from a 3rd party dependent DLL/so from my DLL/so?

Tags: linux, gcc, linker

Let's say my software project, A, ships as a shared library (libA.so).  A uses a 3rd party library, B, which it links as a shared library when I build libA.so.  (Though I'm happy to use libB.a rather than libB.so if that is part of the solution.)  B is used by A, but strictly speaking, the apps that link against A don't need to see any of the symbols of B, it's not part of A's public API.

OK, here's the problem: some apps link against B for their own reasons, as well as against A, and if the versions of B (the one the app uses and the one A linked against at build time) don't match, there are random crashes as the symbols clash.

How can I cause all of B's symbols to resolve against A's needs, but not export as visible symbols in libA.so?  In other words, I don't want an app linking against A to ever directly resolve against B's symbols.  Is that even possible?

Primarily, I need a solution on Linux, though knowing how to solve the problem on OSX and/or Windows will also be helpful down the road.

I understand how to restrict visibility of the symbols in A itself (that aren't necessary to be part of the public API of A), but how do I do this for dependent library B?

Answer (score 1):

> ... some apps link against B for their own reasons ...
>   In other words, I don't want an app linking against A to ever directly resolve against B's symbols.

Think about it: if you prevent the app from linking against B's symbols, how would the app satisfy "its own reason to link against B" ?

Your question (as stated) is self-contradictory.

Now, multiple versions of B used to link different parts of the same executable are clearly a problem.

The only solution I know of is for you to "hide" the fact that you are using B completely. The way to do that is:

1. Link against `libB.a`, and
2. Hide B's symbols inside `libA.so`, so they are not exported.
   This is easiest to achieve with a [linker version script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/452955/50617).

Please note that if `libB.a` is distributed under e.g. GPL, putting a copy of it into `libA.so` may require that you satisfy `libB`s licensing terms. Tread carefully and consult your lawyer.