# Limiting shared library symbol visibility on Solaris

Tags: linker, shared-libraries, solaris, visibility

With GCC (on Linux) I can easily [limit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/437525/427158) the [visibility](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.0/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html#Code-Gen-Options) of [symbols in shared](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) libraries.

What are my options on Solaris (10)?

Do these GCC features also work with GCC on Solaris (especially with a GCC that uses the Solaris linker/assembler)?

And does the Solaris Studio C-compiler/linker provide similar attributes/pragmas for controlling the visibility of symbols (i.e. for setting the default to hidden and explicitly marking symbols as visible)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't answer about gcc visibility on Solaris, but

In the Sun Studio there are

> compiler option -xldscope, and the code attributes _*global/*_hidden

according to http://lists.qt.nokia.com/public/qt-interest/2010-January/017893.html

http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/merge_requests/433:

> SunStudio since version 8 (CC version 5.5) has had the ability to control symbol visibility in ABI via the linker option

```
 -xldscope=[global|symbolic|hidden]
```

> and via code "attributes" __global, __symbolic & __hidden.

```
-xldscope=global maps to GCC's -fvisibility=default 
-xldscope=symbolic maps to GCC's -fvisibility=protected 
-xldscope=hidden maps to GCC's -fvisibility=hidden

__global maps to GCC's __attribute__((visibility("default")) 
__symbolic maps to GCC's __attribute__((visibility("protected")) 
__hidden maps to GCC's __attribute__((visibility("hidden"))
```

And there is an overview from Sun: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris/symbol-scope-140496.html

> Reducing Symbol Scope with Sun Studio C/C++   by Giri Mandalika, May, 2005 (revised March 22, 2006)

Answer (score 4):

I've tested some declaration annotation methods on a Solaris 10 machine. Surprisingly, the Solaris Studio C compiler also supports the GCC-hidden-function attribute.

A GCC configured with Solaris `as`/`ld` correctly implements the visibiltiy function attribute.

Thus, using the GCC function attribute syntax should be the most convenient/portable method because it works on Linux/GCC, Solaris/GCC and Solaris/Sol-Studio.

See the following table for an overview of the effects setting a function visibility to hidden.

### Results

```
                                                     .dynsym|.symtab
System           Compiler     Visibility      nm     readelf           link-error
                                                     elfdump
―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――
Linux Fedora 17  gcc-4.7.2    not specified   T      GLOBAL DEFAULT    no
Linux Fedora 17  gcc-4.7.2    attr-hidden     t      -|LOCAL DEFAULT   yes
Solaris 10       gcc-4.8      not specified   GLOB   GLOB D            no
Solaris 10       gcc-4.8      attr-hidden     LOCL   -|LOCL H          yes
Solaris 10       cc-12.3      attr-hidden     LOCL   -|LOCL H          yes
Solaris 10       cc-12.3      __hidden        LOCL   -|LOCL H          yes
```

### Methods

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "power3.h"
#include "power2.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  printf("Result: %d\n", power3(atoi(argv[1])));
  // should result in a link error when symbol is hidden
  printf("Result: %d\n", power2(atoi(argv[1])));

  return 0;
}
```

power2.h:

```
#ifndef POWER2_H
#define POWER2_H

#if !defined(NO_HIDE)
  #if defined(__GNUC__) || defined(FORCE_GCC)
    __attribute__((visibility("hidden")))
    #warning Using GNU-C function attribute
  #elif defined(__SUNPRO_C)
    __hidden
    #warning Using SUNPRO-C qualifier
  #endif
#endif
int
// GCC attribute also possible here
    power2(int x);
#endif
```

power3.h:

```
#ifndef POWER3_H
#define POWER3_H
int power3(int x);
#endif
```

power3.c

```
#include "power3.h"
#include "power2.h"
int power3(int x)
{
  return power2(x)*x;
}
```

Build commands:

```
cc -g   -c -o main.o main.c
cc  -g -fpic -c -o power3.po power3.c
cc  -g -fpic -c -o power2.po power2.c
cc -shared -fpic -o libpower.so power3.po power2.po
cc -L$PWD -Wl,-R$PWD
```

Introspection:

Under Linux:

```
nm libpower.so | grep power
readelf --dyn-sym libpower.so | grep power
readelf -s libpower.so | grep 'FUNC.*power'
```

Under Solaris:

```
/usr/ccs/bin/nm libpower.so | grep 'FUNC.*power'
/usr/ccs/bin/elfdump -N .dynsym libpower.so | grep 'FUNC.*power'
elfdump -N .symtab libpower.so | grep 'FUNC.*power'
```

System details:

The Solaris 10 system is a SPARC machine and the GCC uses `as`/`ld` from `/usr/ccs/bin`. The Solaris Studio version is 12.3 with patches applied (2013/02/04).

### Sources

- [Oracle Solaris Studio 12.3 C User's Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24457_01/pdf/E21990.pdf). Section 2.2 *Linker Scoping Specifiers*, page 32 (`__hidden`). Section 2.9 *Supported Attributes*, page 40 (`__visibility`).
- Solaris Studio 12.3 cc man page, `cc(1)` (`__hidden`)
- [Reducing Symbol Scope with Sun Studio C/C++](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/jp/server-storage/solarisstudio/overview/symbol-scope-140496.html) by Giri Mandalika, 2005/2006
- [GCC 4.8 manual, -fvisibility paragraph](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.0/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html#Code-Gen-Options)

### Global switches

For completeness, visibility of functions (and other symbols) can also be influenced by other means:

```
GCC-method                            Sol equivalent     effect
――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――
#pragma GCC visibility push(hidden)   -                  everything between push/pop
#pragma GCC visibility pop            -                  has default visibility hidden
#pragma GCC visibility push(default)  -                  ~ default to default-visibility
#pragma GCC visibility pop            -
-fvisibility=hidden                   -xldscope=hidden   sets default visibility of
-fvisibility=default                  -xldscope=global   a translation unit
```

The ELF standard also defines symbol visibilities internal and protected - which are also understood by the compilers, but which are less useful in general.

Comment: The Solaris Studio releases support a subset of the gcc attributes, and that subset has grown from release to release, so you may need to check Studio versions if you're doing this in a code base that may be compiled with different versions of the compilers.   For instance [see X.Org's X11/Xfuncproto.h header checks for `__attribute((noreturn))`](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/proto/x11proto/tree/Xfuncproto.h.in?id=xproto-7.0.24#n115).

Comment: It looks as though `__attribute__((visibility("default")))` doesn't behave the same as `__global` as the compiler manual seems to indicate.  The latter still exports it as a global symbol when `-xldscope=hidden` is used, but the former appears to be equivalent to not specifying the attribute at all.

Comment: The odd thing is when you compile w/out linking using that attribute and `-xldscope=hidden`, GNU nm sees the symbol as being global, but after linking it into the library the symbol becomes local and I'm not entirely sure why.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use version script files. This works on Linux, Solaris/GCC and Solaris/CC.

### Example

Consider a shared library where only a function `power3()` should be globally available. It uses `power2()` which is defined in another translation unit and `power2()` should be hidden.

Following version script specifies this:

```
$ cat vscript
{
  global: power3;
  local: *;
};
```

You can use one file for linking on Linux and Solaris - Linux/Solaris seem to understand the same syntactic constructs.

### Build commands

```
System            Compiler   Link command
―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――
Linux Fedora 17   gcc-4.7.2  cc -shared -Wl,--version-script,vscript -fpic -o libpower.so ...
Solaris 10        gcc-4.8*   gcc -shared -Wl,-M,vscript -fpic -o libpower.so ...
Solaris 10        cc 12.3    cc -shared -M vscript -fpic -o libpower.so ...
```

Note that the GCC on Solaris is configured to use `ld`/`as` from `/usr/ccs/bin`.

Comment: It works, and I like that it's possible, but I fully expected `-xldscope=hidden` to be at least partially equivalent to doing this.  The  compiler manual claims it's a linker flag, but I tested by running separate compile / link steps (each with this flag); the compile step makes use of the flag, but the link step doesn't pass anything different to the linker.