# link a static library to a shared library and hide exported symbols

Tags: c++, linker, static-linking, ld-preload

I am having an annoying problem with the linker. I want to link some symbols from a shared library to a static library, but not export its symbols (ie, I cannot simply merge the libraries or link with `--whole-archive`). What I want is link (as in, like linking an executable, solving undefined symbols) my shared library to a static one and remove the undefined symbols.

The thing I am looking for is probably just a linker option but I can't put my finger on it.

I'll try to describe the problem the best I can (it's not that easy) and then provide a toy minimal example to play with.

***Quick description:***

I want to use the `LD_PRELOAD` trick to trap some function calls in an executable. This executable is linked against a third party shared library, which contains the function definition of the functions I want to trap.

This third party library also contains symbols from yet another library, which I am also using in my library, but with a different (non-compatible) version.

What I want to do is compile my shared library and link it at compile time with the definitions of the last (static) library, without exporting the symbols, so that my shared library uses a different version from the one I want to trap.

***Simplified problem description***

I have a third party library called `libext.so`, for which I don't have the source code. This defines a function `bar` and uses a function `foo` from another library, but the symbols are both defined there:

```
$> nm libext.so
0000000000000a16 T bar
00000000000009e8 T foo
```

As I mentioned, `foo` is an external dependency, for which I want to use a newer version. I have an updated library for it, let's call it `libfoo.a`:

```
$> nm libfoo.a
0000000000000000 T foo
```

Now the problem is that I want to create a dynamic library which re-defines `bar`, but I want my library to use the the definition of `foo` from `libfoo.a` and i want the functions from `libext.so` to call the function `foo` from `libext.so`. In other words, I want a compile time linkage of my library to `libfoo.a`.

What I am looking for is define a library which uses `libfoo.a` but doesn't export its symbols. If I link my library to `libfoo.a`, I get:

```
$> nm libmine.so
0000000000000a78 T bar
0000000000000b2c T foo
```

Which means I overload both `foo` and `bar` (i don't want to override `foo`). If i don't link my library to `libfoo.a`, I get:

```
$> nm libmine.so
0000000000000a78 T bar
                 U foo
```

So my library will use their version of `foo`, which I don't want either. What I want is:

```
$> nm libmine.so
0000000000000a78 T bar
```

Where `foo` is linked at compile time and its symbol not exported.

***Minimal example***

You don't need to read this, but you can use it to play around and find a solution.

`bar.cpp`: represents the third party app I don't have the code for:

```
#include <iostream>
extern "C" void foo(){ std::cerr << "old::foo" << std::endl; }
extern "C" void bar(){ std::cerr << "old::bar" << std::endl; foo(); }
```

`foo.cpp`: represents a newer version of a function used by both my lib and the third party:

```
#include <iostream>
extern "C" void foo(){ std::cerr << "new::foo" << std::endl; }
```

`trap.cpp`: the code from my library, it traps `bar`, calls the new `foo` and forwards:

```
#include <iostream>
extern "C" {
  #include <dlfcn.h>
}
extern "C" void foo();
extern "C" void bar(){
  std::cerr << "new::bar" << std::endl;
  foo(); // Should be new::foo
  void (*fwd)() = (void(*)())dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "bar");
  fwd(); // Should use old::foo
}
```

`exec.cpp`: a dummy executable to call `bar`:

```
extern "C" void bar();

int main(){
  bar();
}
```

`Makefile`: Unix only, sorry

```
default:
    # The third party library
    g++ -c -o bar.o bar.cpp -fpic
    gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libext.so -o libext.so bar.o
    # The updated library
    g++ -c -o foo.o foo.cpp -fPIC
    ar rcs libfoo.a foo.o
    # My trapping library
    g++ -c -o trap.o trap.cpp -fPIC
    gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libmine.so -o libmine.so trap.o -ldl -L. -lfoo
    # The dummy executable
    g++ -o test exec.cpp -L. libext.so
```

In this case, `bar` calls `foo`; the normal execution is:

```
$> ./test
old::bar
old::foo
```

Preloading my library intercepts `bar`, calls my `foo` and forwards `bar`, the current execution is:

```
$> LD_PRELOAD=libmine.so ./test
new::bar
new::foo
old::bar
new::foo
```

The last line is wrong, the desired output is:

```
$> LD_PRELOAD=libmine.so ./test
new::bar
new::foo
old::bar
old::foo
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use a linker version script, which exports the symbol(s) you want (`bar` here) and *hides* everything else.

Example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/452955/50617).

Comment: That worked. It's weird that there is no linker option to lower the visibility of the linked dependencies directly at link time.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the accepted answer, we can use a linker version script to change the scope of the undesired symbols from global to local:

```
BAR {
  global: bar;
  local: *;
};
```

Compiling with the linker version shows `foo` is local and the program now behaves as expected:

```
$> gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libmine.so -Wl,--version-script=libmine.version -o libmine.so trap.o -ldl -L. -lfoo
$> nm libmine.so
0000000000000978 T bar
0000000000000000 A BAR  
0000000000000a2c t foo
$> LD_PRELOAD=libmine.so ./test
new::bar
new::foo
old::bar
old::foo
```

---

An alternative is to re-compile `libfoo.a` with the attribute `-fvisibility=hidden` and link against that. The visibility of the exported symbols is then local too, and the behavior is the same as above.

---

<sup>Note: This answer was originally written by OP (Thibaut) in the question.</sup>