# How to embed a shared library into another one?

Tags: python, c++, linker, shared-libraries, embedded-resource

assume I extend a C++ function to python by creating **libA.so**, but  libA.so **depends** also on another shared library **libB.so**. I want to distribute libA.so to a final user in a way that it already **contains** (embeds) libB.so, i.e. the final user does **not need to obtain libB.so** or to set his/her LD_LIBRARY_PATH to  point to the folder containing libB.so (in the case this library is present in the final user's file system).

So basically I want to create a shared library libA.so which does not refer to any other (static or shared) library.

Question 1: Is there a way to do this in linux?

Question 2: Can this be done by configuring a python setup script based on distutils.core? (probably question 1 will also provide the answer to this)

Thanks

Comment: You cannot embed a `.so` file into another `.so` file. If it was a `.a` file or a bunch of `.o` files, it can easily be done using `ar` and then statically linked to. It `might` be possible to embed both `.so` files into your application and extract it at run time then load it using `dlopen` and `dlsym`.

Comment: Append `libB.a` to the list of files to be compiled.

Comment: is there a way to transform libB.so into libB.a so that ar (by the way, is this a linker option?) can be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question 1: Is there a way to do this in linux?

No. UNIX systems in general (with notable exception of AIX), and Linux in particular, consider `a.out` and `libfoo.so` "fully cooked" and "final". There is no way to relink them.

> I want to create a shared library libA.so which does not refer to any other (static or shared) library.

You *can* do that by linking *objects* that would have been linked into `libB.so` into `libA.so` instead.

Note however that if your users want to link against `libB.so` on their own, then you need to be extra careful to not violate [one definition rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule). This can be achieved by hiding all `libB`'s symols inside `libA.so` (instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/452955/50617)).

Also note that doing this may have licensing implications -- if `libB` is distributed under GPL, then linking it into `libA` creates a derivative work that must also be distributed under the same license.