# Compiled shared library has dependency on specific libicuuc.so.46 version

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, shared-libraries, icu

I am compiling a shared library using g++ on SUse Linux with cmake that depends on libicuuc.so and friends.

Suse has libicuuc.so, libicuuc.so.46 and libicuuc.so.46.1 in /usr/lib.

Now when I use ldd to list the dependencies of my library it tells me that it depends on libicuuc.so.46.

Since I want to distribute my library in binary form (it takes about 45 minutes to compile on a fast PC) this dependency is a problem. The target PCs have different versions of libicuuc.so.

What can I do so that my library depends on libicuuc.so and not libicuuc.so.46?

I tried to remove the so.46 versions in my /usr/lib folder before compiling but libicuuc.so depends on libicudata.so.46 so I keep that dependency on a 46 version what I try to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about external library versioning [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E26507/chapter5-5.html).

> What can I do so that my library depends on libicuuc.so and not libicuuc.so.46?

You can't do anything about that. The `libicuuc.so` that you have has `SONAME` set to `libicuuc.so.46`, and the linker dutifully records that dependency (as it *should*).

If developers release `libicuuc.so.47`, they would do so because the new library is not ABI-compatible with the old one (at least that's what they should do if they are not clueless).

If your library loaded `libcuuc.so.47` (as you want it to), it would most likely crash due to the ABI incompatibility. Or worse: corrupt your end user's data. So achieving your desired result would get you into *worse* trouble than what you have now (not running is better than randomly crashing or corrupting data).

**Update:**

The `libicuuc.so` [documentation](http://userguide.icu-project.org/packaging#TOC-POSIX-Library-Names) *explicitly* states that "Binary compatibility is for versions that share the same major+minor number."

That means: you *can't* link a library compiled with version 4.6 (SONAME `libicuuc.so.46`) and expect it work with version 4.7.

You *must* either rebuild your library for each version of ICUUC, or distribute matching `libicuuc.so.NN` with your library (and hope that the user is not already using some other version of `libicuuc`).

Another possible alternative: statically link `libicuuc.a` into your library, and [hide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/452955/50617) all of `libicuuc.a` symbols so they don't conflict with anything else. Note: this has licensing implications.

Comment: I did assume that version 46 has a subset of the 47 ABI and the library that was linked with a 46 library could just pick the parts it needed from the 47 ABI. But I have no detailed knowledge about shared library ABIs and how the linker uses them.

Comment: @Georg You assumption is incorrect. Adding new parts to the ABI does *not* require incrementing external version; only *incompatible* change to *existing* ABI does.

Comment: What do you recommend that I do?  When I compile from source the library will work with any version of libicuuc. When I compile it, it will only work with the libicuuc version that is currently installed.  If I make a binary rpm this will just work if the target PC has the same shared library version of libicuuc that I had on my PC where I compiled it.  I thought libicuuc.so was intended to allow programs to ask to load just ".so" and this will then point to any version that happens to be installed.

Comment: I will give the static approach a try. I wanted to make a stripped down bare bones version of ICU anyway. Thank you for your detailed information!