# Corresponding option for linker in linux

Tags: c, linux, linker, ld, aix

With IBM's `ld` linker there is one option `-bexport :filename`.

In this file we have the names of the functions we need to export at the time of linking.

But in ubuntu I am not able to find this and it gives following error
`` /usr/bin/ld: invalid BFD target `export:stx_export' ``

Please suggest what can I do in ubuntu to export such files at the time of linking. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Documentation is here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/

Comment: found --dynamic-list=stx_export
but i am not able to find the format of dynamic list file.
i tried 
global:TPCALL;
global:TPACALL;
but it gave the error
 syntax error in dynamic list

Answer (score 1):

There is a **-retain-symbols-file** option in GNU ld:

```
AIX: -Wl,-bE:something.exp
GNU: -Wl,--retain-symbols-file=something.exp
```

Edit: As Employed Russian pointed out, when creating a shared lib, ld doesn't honor this file. Thank you, Employed Russian.

Note: if we use libtool with option **-export-symbols** it uses options like -Wl,-version-script -Wl,.libs/libfoo.ver, where libfoo.ver is created from the export file automagically:

```
{ global:
const_var2ptr;
const_var2ptr2;
init_var;
lt_libaix_modcall_LTX_preloaded_symbols;
uninit_var;
var2ptr;
vartest2_fun;
vartest_fun;
local: *; };
```

Comment: Hey thanks for this option.
but when i used this option at the time of linking ..i think it is only considering the symbols that are in the file...not corresponding the symbols linked.

Comment: Couldn't say I understand your problem... What command did you try, what result did you expect, and what happened instead?

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond As far as I can tell, `--retain-symbols-file` does absolutely *nothing* when linking a shared library.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to achieve this on Linux is with a version script. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/452955/50617) provides details.