# choose exported symbols when linking an elf application and shared library

Tags: linker, elf

when linking an elf application or share library, I want to choose which symbols to export. By default, when linking an application no function symbol is exported and when linking a shared library all function symbols are exported. Is there any way to control which symbols to export? When linking an application, I can use `-rdynamic` or `-Wl,--export-dynamic` to get all symbols, and I can use `-Wl,--dynamic-list <symfile>` to get only some symbols. However when linking a library, are those options ignored?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limiting visibility of symbols when linking shared libraries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/435352/limiting-visibility-of-symbols-when-linking-shared-libraries)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found out after testing a little:

- for ELF applications, you can use `-rdynamic` or `-Wl,--export-dynamic` to export all symbols, or you can use `-Wl,--dynamic-list <sym-file>` to export only some symbols when linking your application through `gcc`.
- for ELF libraries, you can't use `-rdynamic`, `-Wl,--export-dynamic` or `-Wl,--dynamic-list <symfile>`, you must use `-Wl,--version-script=<verfile>` when linking your library through `gcc`.

The version-script and the sym-file are almost the same, except that for sym-file you do not code a version and a scope. Documentation: [gnu ld](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#Options)

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to control which symbols to export?

The usual way to control symbol visibility in shared library is either

1. Use linker script, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/452955/50617), or
2. Use `__attribute__((visibility("default")))` on symbols you explicitly want to export and build with `-fvisibility=hidden` (which will hide everything else).