# symbols visibility - shared library vs dll

Tags: c++, dll, shared-libraries, symbols, visibility

I have a C++ dynamic library which defines global symbols - functions. When I compile the library using gcc those symbols are by default visible. It may leads to symbol collisions when an application links to a few libraries. I can put functions in the namespace and hide private functions using the compilation flag `-fvisibility=hidden`. Then API functions should contain the following attribute: `__attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))`

Let's assume that I compile a dynamic library on Windows using Microsoft Visual Studio compiler.
Some symbols are not defined with `__declspec(dllexport)` Does it mean that those symbols will be hidden ?

Comment: Are you trying to compare GCC and ELF shared objects to MSVC and Windows DLLs? Or just Windows DLLs with different compilers? Or something else?

Comment: As specified in the question description: GCC and ELF shared objects vs MSVC and Windows DLLs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both POSIX and Windows provide different means to control symbol visibility. Source-code annotations (`__attribute__((visibility("default")))` and `__declspec(dllexport)`) are the most common way to do this. Windows `__declspec(dllexport)` is indeed absolutely equivalent to POSIX `-fvisibility=hidden` + `__attribute__((visibility("default")))` in this respect.

But both platforms also provide other alternatives to set visibility e.g. [export symbol files and version scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34879052/2170527) on POSIX and [DEF files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/exporting-from-a-dll-using-def-files?view=msvc-160) on Windows. These alternatives are less common (mainly because they are less portable and prevent some important optimizations).

So whether `__declspec` is "enough" and in what sense entirely depends on your project's buildscripts. If DEF files and linker scripts are not used - all symbols not explicitly marked with `__declspec(dllexport)` will be hidden.

Comment: Could you please add a clear answer for the question ?

Comment: Sorry if my comment sounds insulting - it hasn't been my intention.