# Minimal working example Ctypes and cmakes: function not found

Tags: python, c++, cmake, ctypes

I'm trying to create a minimal working example to run c++ code in python, while using Cmake and Ctypes.

These are my files:

**get_five.cpp**

```
extern "C" {
    int get_five(){
        return 5;
    }
}
```

**get_five.py**

```
import ctypes
import os

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
dll_file = os.path.join(dir_path,'get_five.dll')

lib = ctypes.CDLL(dll_file)
print(lib.get_five())
```

**CmakeLists.txt**

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED( VERSION 3.3 )
PROJECT( Test )
add_library(get_five SHARED get_five.cpp)
```

To compile and run this code, i use the following commands:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
cmake --build .
```

Then, i copy the file build/debug/test.dll to the root directory and run get_five.py. This gives the following error:

> AttributeError: function 'get_five' not found

Compiling with g++ with the command

```
g++ get_five.cpp -shared -o get_five.dll
```

works fine, so I am assuming I'm making a mistake with the Cmake part. Any suggestions how to make this MWE work correctly?

Comment: It seems like you're not exporting any function from the DLL. See [here](https://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/computing/building-dlls-with-mingw/) for a tutorial on how to do it.

Comment: @vre This was it, thanks! A question:, why is this not needed when compiling with g++?

Comment: @vre I created an answer based on your comment. Feel free to copy it and I'll mark it as accepted answer and delete mine.

Comment: pybind11 module ?

Comment: gcc sets by default all symbols in a shared object visible. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67400448/symbols-visibility-shared-library-vs-dll) for further details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function get_five was not exported. The following MWE works correctly:

**get_five.cpp**

```
extern "C" {
    __declspec(dllexport) int __cdecl get_five(){
        return 5;
    }
}
```

**get_five.py**

```
import ctypes
import os

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
dll_file = os.path.join(dir_path,'get_five.dll')

lib = ctypes.CDLL(dll_file)
print(lib.get_five())
```

**CmakeLists.txt**

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED( VERSION 3.3 )
PROJECT( Test )
add_library(get_five SHARED get_five.cpp)
```

To compile and run this code, i use the following commands:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
cmake --build .
```

Then, i copy the file build/debug/test.dll to the root directory and run get_five.py.