# nm symbol output t vs T in a shared so library

Tags: gcc, linker, shared-libraries

I have added a new function (fuse_lowlevel_notify_inval_directory) in user space fuse library.
The compilation and creation of libfuse.so is finished without error.
But when my application tries to use this new function, the linker is throwing error: undefined reference to `fuse_lowlevel_notify_inval_directory'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

When I checked with nm

```
nm ../libfuse.so | grep inval
00000000000154ed T fuse_invalidate
**000000000001e142 t fuse_lowlevel_notify_inval_directory**
000000000001e26c T fuse_lowlevel_notify_inval_entry
000000000001e1cb T fuse_lowlevel_notify_inval_inode
```

T/t means the symbol is present in text section. if uppercase, the symbol is global (external). I suspect this is the issue. The new added function is showing lowercase t while other older functions are having upper case T. Any idea about what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Apparently you've failed to give your function external linkage. Need the code, at least, to be any more helpful.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

> Any idea about what I might be doing wrong?

The `t` function is indeed local to the library. This could happen due to a number or reasons. The most likely ones are:

1. You declared the function `static`, or
2. You compiled the library with `-fvisibility=hidden` and did *not* have `__attribute__((visibility("default")))` on the function, or
3. You linked this library with a linker version script (i.e. with `--version-script=libfoo.version` flag) that hides all functions, except those which are explicitly exported, and you didn't add your function to that list. 
   See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435352/limiting-visibility-of-symbols-when-linking-shared-libraries) example of using `--version-script` to limit symbol visibility.

Comment: The third point was the issue. Fuse has some version script and explicitly export the functions.

Comment: But why does a static/local function show in the symbol list? I supposed that only a function which can be called be external environment should show in the symbol list?

Comment: @xnervwang " I supposed that only a function which can be called be external environment should show in the symbol list?" -- you supposed wrong. On UNIX local symbols are included by default in the symbol table to ease debugging.