# Hiding non-API symbols in library

Tags: c, posix, ld, static-linking, object-files

Suppose I have a library *foo* which consists of the modules *foo* and *util* and has the following source tree:

```
foo/
    foo.c
    foo.h
    util.c
    util.h
```

The public API of the library is defined in *foo.h* and all global identifiers are properly prefixed with `foo_` or `util_`. The module *util* is only used by *foo*. To prevent name clashes with other modules named *util* I want to create a (static) library in which only identifiers from module *foo* are visible. How can I do this?

Edit: I have searched the internet quite extensively but surprisingly this seems to be one of those unsolved problems in computer science.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before each variable and function declaration in `util.h`, define a macro constant which renames the declared identifier by adding the library prefix `foo_`, for instance

```
#define util_x foo_util_x
extern int util_x;   

#define util_f foo_util_f
void util_f(void);

...
```

With these definitions in place, no other parts of the code need to be changed, and all global symbols in the object file `util.o` will be prefixed with `foo_`. This means that name collisions are less likely to occur.

Answer (score 2):

There are probably other possible approaches, but here's one:

You might consider including the file `util.c` within `foo.c` and making all the util functions / globals static. i.e.:

```
#include "util.c"
// ...
```

This works the same as `*.h` files, it simply ports the whole source into `foo.c`, nesting `util.c` and making all the static data available.

When I do this, I rename the file to `.inc` (i.e. `util.c` => `util.inc`)...

```
#include "util.inc"
// ...
```

...it's an older convention I picked up somewhere, though it might conflict with assembler files, so you'll have to use your own discretion.

**EDIT**

Another approach might require linker specific directives. For example, [this SO answer details GNU's `ld` to achieve this goal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/452955/4025095). There are other approaches as well, listed in that same thread.

Comment: That's an interesting approach. However, I would prefer a solution which works at the object file level.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom I can definitely understand this preference. However, I think this would be a linker specific solution. I edited my answer with details.

Comment: The GNU ld approach you linked to requires manually managing a file of exported symbols. I should be able to say that all symbols in util.o should be hidden.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom The same thread I linked to offers some other approaches as well. However, I think the only portable approach that will work regardless of compiler or linker would end up being the `#include` approach. Personally, I target `gcc` and `clang`, so I have an easy time using non-portable features.

Answer (score 0):

The following is GCC-specific.

You can mark each utility function with

```
__attribute__((visibility ("hidden")))
```

which will prevent it from being linked to from another shared object.

You can apply this to a series of declarations by surrounding them with

```
#pragma GCC visibility push(hidden)
/* ... */
#pragma GCC visibility pop
```

or use `-fvisibility=hidden` when compiling the object, which applies to declarations without an explicit visibility (e.g. neither `__attribute__((visibility))` nor `#pragma GCC visibility`).