# Can I make some symbols only visible to other library members?

Tags: c, linker, shared-libraries, static-libraries, symbols

Consider 3 C source files:

```
/* widgets.c */
void widgetTwiddle ( struct widget * w ) {
    utilityTwiddle(&w->bits, 1);
}
```

and

```
/* wombats.c */
void wombatTwiddle ( struct wombat * w ) {
    utilityTwiddle(&w->bits, 1);
}
```

and

```
/* utility.c */
void utilityTwiddle ( int * bitsPtr, int bits ) {
    *bitsPtr ^= bits;
}
```

which get compiled and put in a library (say, either libww.a or libww.so).
Is there a way to make `utilityTwiddle()` visible and usable by the other two library members, but not be visible to to those who link to the library?  That is, given this:

```
/* appl.c */
extern void utilityTwiddle ( int * bitsPtr, int bits );
int main ( void ) {
    int bits;
    utilityTwiddle(&bits, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

and

```
cc -o appl appl.c -lww
```

it would fail to link because `utilityTwiddle()` is not visible to `appl.c`.  And, consequently `appl.c` would be free to define its own `utilityTwiddle` function or variable.

**[EDIT]** And hopefully obviously, we would like this to work:

```
/* workingappl.c */
extern void wombatTwiddle ( struct wombat * wPtr );
int main ( void ) {
    struct wombat w = { .bits = 0 };
    wombatTwiddle(&w);
    return 0;
}
```

This [Limiting visibility of symbols when linking shared libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435352/limiting-visibility-of-symbols-when-linking-shared-libraries) seems related, but it doesn't seem to address whether the symbols suppressed are available to other library members.

**[EDIT2]** I have sort-of figured out a way to do it without modifying the C source.  Add a map file:

```
/* utility.map */
{ local: *; };
```

and then do:

```
$ gcc -shared -o utility.so utility.c -fPIC -Wl,--version-script=utility.map
```

gives us a dynamic symbol table w/o `utilityTwiddle`:

```
$ nm -D utility.so
             w _Jv_RegisterClasses
             w __cxa_finalize
             w __gmon_start__
```

but it's not clear to me how to effectively go from this to building a shared library with all three source files.  If I put all three source files on the command line, the symbols from all three are hidden.  If there is a way to incrementally build the shared library, I could have two simple map files (one to export nothing, one to export everything).  Is this doable or is the only option something like this:

```
/* libww.map */
{ global: list; of; all; symbols; to; export; local: *; };
```

and

```
$ gcc -shared -o libww.so *.c -fPIC -Wl,--version-script=libww.map
```

**[EDIT3]**
Boy, it sure seems like this also ought to be possible without using shared libraries.  If I do:

```
ld -r -o wboth.o widgets.o wombats.o utility.o
```

I can see that the linker has resolved to location of `utilityTwiddle()` where `widgetTwiddle()` and `wombatTwiddle()` call it:

```
$ objdump -d wboth.o
0000000000000000 <widgetTwiddle>:
   0:   be 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%esi
   5:   e9 00 00 00 00          jmpq   a <widgetTwiddle+0xa>
0000000000000010 <wombatTwiddle>:
  10:   be 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%esi
  15:   e9 00 00 00 00          jmpq   1a <wombatTwiddle+0xa>
0000000000000020 <utilityTwiddle>:
  20:   31 37                   xor    %esi,(%rdi)
  22:   c3                      retq
```

but `utilityTwiddle` remains as a symbol:

```
$ nm wboth.o
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
0000000000000020 T utilityTwiddle
0000000000000000 T widgetTwiddle
0000000000000010 T wombatTwiddle
```

and so if you could find a way to remove that symbol, you could still successfully link against `wboth.o` (I have tested this by binary editing wboth.o) and it still links and runs fine:

```
$ nm wboth.o
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
0000000000000000 T widgetTwiddle
0000000000000010 T wombatTwiddle
0000000000000020 T xtilityTwiddle
```

Comment: nope, there are either global or local symbols. if you export them from one place, they are visible to everyone. On some platforms you can have `weak` symbol definitions which could be overwritten with 'strong' versions. Just be careful. Those things is extremely difficult to debug and better not to use them.

Comment: Is libww static or shared? For shared libraries the question you cite gives the answer (and to answer your question, yes, suppressed symbols are available to other library members). For static libraries there's no way to control visibility.

Comment: I wasn't specifying a library type, but it appears that shared is the only workable option.

Comment: And there is always the 'ghetto' solution: `#define utilityTwiddle gibberish_name`

Answer (score 5):

You can't achieve what you want by creating a static library `libww.a`. If you
read [static-libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/static-libraries/info) you
will see why. A static library can be used to offer a bunch *N* of object files
to the linker, from which it will extract *k* (possibly = 0) that it needs and link *them*. So you
can't achieve anything by linking with the static library that you can't achieve by
linking those *k* object files directly. For linkage purposes, static libraries don't really
exist.

But *shared* libraries really do exist for linkage purposes and the global symbols exposed by shared library
acquire an additional property, *dynamic visibility*, that exists precisely for your
purpose. The dynamically visible symbols are a subset of the global symbols: they are
the global symbols that are visible for *dynamic* linkage, i.e. for linking the shared library
with something else (a program or another shared library).

Dynamic visibility is not an attribute that source language standards say anything
about, because they don't say anything about dynamic linkage. So controlling the
dynamic visibility of symbols has to be done in an individual way by a toolchain that
does support dynamic linkage. GCC does it with the compiler-specific declaration
qualifier<sup>1</sup>:

```
__attribute__((visibility("default|hidden|protected|internal")
```

and/or the compiler switch<sup>2</sup>:

```
-fvisibility=default|hidden|protected|internal
```

Here's a demo of how build `libww.so` so that `utilityTwiddle` is hidden from
clients of the library while `wombatTwiddle` and `widgetTwiddle` are visible.

Your source code needs fleshed out a bit in one way or another to compile.
Here's a first cut:

**ww.h (1)**

```
#ifndef WW_H
#define WW_H

struct widget {
    int bits;
};

struct wombat {
    int bits;
};

extern void widgetTwiddle ( struct widget * w );
extern void wombatTwiddle ( struct wombat * w );

#endif
```

**utility.h (1)**

```
#ifndef UTILITY_H
#define UTILITY_H

extern void utilityTwiddle ( int * bitsPtr, int bits );

#endif
```

**utility.c**

```
#include "utility.h"

void utilityTwiddle ( int * bitsPtr, int bits ) {
    *bitsPtr ^= bits;
}
```

**wombats.c**

```
#include "utility.h"
#include "ww.h"

void wombatTwiddle ( struct wombat * w ) {
    utilityTwiddle(&w->bits, 1);
}
```

**widgets.c**

```
#include "utility.h"
#include "ww.h"

void widgetTwiddle ( struct widget * w ) {
    utilityTwiddle(&w->bits, 1);
}
```

Compile all the `*.c` files to `*.o` files in the default manner:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -c widgets.c wombats.c utility.c
```

and link them into `libww.so` in the default manner:

```
$ gcc -shared -o libww.so widgets.o wombats.o utility.o
```

Here are `*Twiddle` symbols in the global symbol table of `libww.so`

```
$ nm libww.so | egrep '*Twiddle'
000000000000063a T utilityTwiddle
00000000000005fa T widgetTwiddle
000000000000061a T wombatTwiddle
```

This is just the sum of the global (`extern`) `*Twiddle` symbols that went into the linkage
of `libww.so` from the object files. They're all *defined* (`T`), as they'd have to be
if the library itself was to be linked without external `*Twiddle` dependencies.

Any ELF file (object file, shared library, program) has a global symbol table, but
a shared library also has a *dynamic* symbol table. Here are the `*Twiddle` symbols in the dynamic symbol table of `libww.so`:

```
$ nm -D libww.so | egrep '*Twiddle'
000000000000063a T utilityTwiddle
00000000000005fa T widgetTwiddle
000000000000061a T wombatTwiddle
```

They're exactly the same. That's what we want to change, so that `utilityTwiddle`
disappears.

Here's a second cut. We have to change the source code slightly.

**utility.h (2)**

```
#ifndef UTILITY_H
#define UTILITY_H

extern void utilityTwiddle ( int * bitsPtr, int bits ) __attribute__((visibility("hidden")));

#endif
```

Then recompile and relink, just as before:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -c widgets.c wombats.c utility.c
$ gcc -shared -o libww.so widgets.o wombats.o utility.o
```

Here are the `*Twiddle` symbols now in the global symbol table:

```
$ nm libww.so | egrep '*Twiddle'
000000000000063a T utilityTwiddle
00000000000005fa T widgetTwiddle
000000000000061a T wombatTwiddle
```

No change there. And here are the `*Twiddle` symbols now in the *dynamic* symbol table:

```
$ nm -D libww.so | egrep '*Twiddle'
00000000000005aa T widgetTwiddle
00000000000005ca T wombatTwiddle
```

`utilityTwiddle` is gone.

Here's a third cut that achieves the same result differently. It's more long-winded
but illustrates how the `-fvisibility` compiler option plays. This time,
`utility.h` is again as per **(1)**, but `ww.h` is:

**ww.h (2)**

```
#ifndef WW_H
#define WW_H

struct widget {
    int bits;
};

struct wombat {
    int bits;
};

extern void widgetTwiddle ( struct widget * w )  __attribute__((visibility("default")));
extern void wombatTwiddle ( struct wombat * w ) __attribute__((visibility("default")));

#endif
```

Now we recompile like so:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -fvisibility=hidden -c widgets.c wombats.c utility.c
```

We're telling the compiler to annotate *every* global symbol it generates with
`__attribute__((visibility("hidden")))` unless there is a countervailing
`__attribute__((visibility("...")))` explicitly in the source code.

Then relink the shared library just as previously. Again we see in the global symbol table:

```
$ nm libww.so | egrep '*Twiddle'
00000000000005ea t utilityTwiddle
00000000000005aa T widgetTwiddle
00000000000005ca T wombatTwiddle
```

and in the dynamic symbol table:

```
$ nm -D libww.so | egrep '*Twiddle'
00000000000005aa T widgetTwiddle
00000000000005ca T wombatTwiddle
```

Finally, to show that removing `utilityTwiddle` from the dynamic symbol table
of `libww.so` in one of these ways really does hide it from clients linking with
`libww.so`. Here's a program that wants to call all the `*Twiddle`s:

**prog.c**

```
#include <ww.h>

extern void utilityTwiddle ( int * bitsPtr, int bits );

int main()
{
    struct widget wi = {1};
    struct wombat wo = {2};
    widgetTwiddle(&wi);
    wombatTwiddle(&wo);
    utilityTwiddle(&wi.bits,wi.bits);
    return 0;
}
```

We have no problem building it like:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -I. -c prog.c
$ gcc -o prog prog.o utility.o widgets.o wombats.o
```

But nobody can build it like:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -I. -c prog.c
$ gcc -o prog prog.o -L. -lww
prog.o: In function `main':
prog.c:(.text+0x4a): undefined reference to `utilityTwiddle'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Be clear that `-fvisibility` is a *compilation* option, not a linkage option.
You pass it to your compilation commands and not to your linkage commands,
because it's effect is the same as sprinkling `__attribute__((visibility("...")))`
qualifiers over the declarations in your source code, which the *compiler* has
to honour by injecting linkage information into the object files that it generates. If
you care to see the evidence of that you can just repeat that last compilation
and request that the assembly files be saved:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -fvisibility=hidden -c widgets.c wombats.c utility.c -save-temps
```

Then compare say:

**widgets.s**

```
    .file   "widgets.c"
    .text
    .globl  widgetTwiddle
    .type   widgetTwiddle, @function
widgetTwiddle:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    subq    $16, %rsp
    movq    %rdi, -8(%rbp)
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    movl    $1, %esi
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    utilityTwiddle@PLT
    nop
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   widgetTwiddle, .-widgetTwiddle
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3) 7.3.0"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

with:

**utility.s**

```
    .file   "utility.c"
    .text
    .globl  utilityTwiddle
    .hidden utilityTwiddle
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    .type   utilityTwiddle, @function
utilityTwiddle:
    ...
    ...
```

---

[1] See the [GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.2.0/gcc/):

- [6.31.1 Common Function Attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.2.0/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes)
- [6.32.1 Common Variable Attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.2.0/gcc/Common-Variable-Attributes.html#Common-Variable-Attributes)

[2] See the [GCC Manual, 3.16 Options for Code Generation Conventions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.2.0/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html#Code-Gen-Options).

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful.  I am wondering if there is a way to accomplish this hiding w/o adding the `__attribute__((..))`s -- just through linking options?