# Stripping only function names of a binary with wildcard exclusion

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, elf, strip

I want to strip my binary in a way where certain function names are retained since the binary is a shared library and all other function names are stripped from the symbol table.

Using the `-g` switch removes all debug information which is great but that does not include the function names.

If I use `--s --wildcard --keep-symbol="blabla_*" --keep-symbol="*blabla*" ...` it still strips too much and breaks compatibility.

Is there any way to just remove function names from the symbol table? I considered rewriting the function names in the `ELF` with an [`ELF parser`](https://github.com/serge1/ELFIO) but it's more tedious than it should be since it seems to be a common enough use case to be either supported by the `strip` command or something else "standardized".

Comment: Did you try `--strip-unneeded`?

Comment: @kaylum: This didn't work since all functions are exported by default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I use --s --wildcard --keep-symbol="blabla_*" --keep-symbol="*blabla*" ... it still strips too much and breaks compatibility.

You are probably confused: since your binary is a shared library, it *doesn't need any* symbols in its regular symbol table (the one displayed by `nm foo.so`) -- it *only* needs the dynamic symbol table (displayed by `nm -D foo.so`), and `strip` doesn't (can't) strip any symbols from the dynamic symbol table.

Therefore, it's a common practice to strip *all* symbols from a shared library, and this can not break compatibility.

It it does for your library, you are not telling the whole story.

P.S. To control *exactly* which symbols are exported in the dynamic symbol table (and thus remain after `strip --strip-all`) use linker version script. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/452955/50617) for details.