# Multiple linking of a static library across different shared objects

Tags: c++, static-linking, dynamic-linking, intel-ipp

Currently I have a setup where there is a 3rd-party supplied shared library, `libfoo.so`. Internally this links in (without using something like `--whole-archive`) a static library (specifically Intel performance primitives) `ipps.a`. This is third party so cannot be modified.

I then build a separate shared library, `libbar.so`, which also statically links `ipps.a`. These two libraries are eventually (along with some others) linked into a plugin, `plugin.so`, which is then loaded at runtime.

Unfortunately this (sometimes) causes runtime issues (I've seen both hanging in the initialization function called when IPP starts up, as well as corrupted data) due to the fact that there are functions from `ipps.a` that exist in both `libbar.so` and `libfoo.so`.

What are the options to deal with this, given that I can't modify the third-party library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What are the options to deal with this, given that I can't modify the third-party library?

Both you and the 3rd party developer have committed a sin -- you are *exposing* symbols from `ipps.a` in your own interface (this is the default on UNIX).

You should hide these symbols instead, using e.g. a linker version script. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/452955/50617).

If you hide all the `ipps.a` symbols in `libbar.so`, then the fact that `libfoo.so` was also linked with `ipps.a` should become irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks. I dug a bit into some of the other answers, and found `-Wl,--exclude-libs` does what I want in this case (easier than using a linker version script).

Comment: I didn't know about `--exclude-libs`, apparently it's quite old. Using version script is a bit more work, but is _better_, because you can _explicitly_ control which symbols you export, and hide implementation details.