# How to avoid dependee library symbols conflict?

Tags: c++, static, fortran, static-linking, dynamic-linking

I have a Fortran executable that statically links against a specific version of hdf5. The executable makes use of a C++ library foo that is statically linked against a different version of hdf5.

The executable refuses to link because of conflict in symbols. Is there a way to avoid this issue without making the C++ library foo dynamic?

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the welcome [tour]. Can't you just link everything with a single version of the library?

Comment: Many versions of the executable will be produced. The hdf5 version of Fortran needs to change for each version. This means, I will have to recompile the C++ library foo with each version, noting that the executable doesn't make use of the hdf5 part of the C++ library foo.

Comment: Yes, always recompile with the right version.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a Fortran executable that statically links against a specific version of hdf5. The executable makes use of a C++ library foo that is statically linked against a different version of hdf5.

This *can* work, but you must *hide* the fact that `foo` contains a version of the `hdf5` library by hiding all of `hdf5` symbols. Doing so will avoid symbol conflicts.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/452955/50617).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But this is specific to g++? Because I am using VC++.