# Building an ELF shared library with static libstdc++ dependency

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, elf, libstdc++

Currently I am trying to implement an ELF shared library, built with `-static-libstdc++` and `-static-libgcc` options. This shared library MUST be built with C++11 and it has some legacy code, besides, it has a very specific design.

If some application links this shared library, their C++ utilities MUST NOT interfere with each other. For example, `std::cout`-related, and hence, `std::ios_base::Init::Init()` (`_ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev`), are awaited to be present in two independent implementations, one static for this specific shared library, and another shared one for the application and it's other shared libraries. However, `LD_DEBUG=all` usage shows that there this specific shared library's C++ utility symbols, like `std::ios_base::Init::Init()`, get bound to the symbols, defined in `libstdc++`, which I try to avoid...

Can such logic be implemented or at least worked around somehow? In any case, I DO NEED separate C++ utility. Thanks in advance!

Comment: A static library is really nothing more than an archive of object files. When you link with a static library, its like linking with the individual object files. When you link with a static library, it becomes an integral part of your executable or shared library. Unfortunately that means global data in your library *will* clash with global data from the process your library is running with. Besides that, a library really shouldn't be using global state, including `std::cout`. If the library needs to use a stream, let the host process pass it in using some kind of initialization function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Currently I am trying to implement an ELF shared library, built with `-static-libstdc++` and `-static-libgcc` options.

Your *best* bet is to *not* do that -- link your library "normally" (so it depends on `libstdc++.so.6` and `libgcc_s.so.1`), and most of your problems would disappear. (See also http://xyproblem.info -- *why* do you want to link `libstdc++` statically?)

> However, `LD_DEBUG=all` usage shows that there this specific shared library's C++ utility symbols, like `std::ios_base::Init::Init()`, get bound to the symbols, defined in `libstdc++`

This statement is *meaningless* when you have two copies of `libstdc++` -- one inside your library, and one "outside" (presumably `libstdc++.so.6`).

What you *probably* mean is that references to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()` from your library get bound to definitions inside `libstdc++.so.6`.

You can avoid this by making all symbols inside your library hidden, and only exposing the "official" interface from it, using linker script. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/452955/50617).

Note:

- Controlling the ABI of a C++ shared library is *much* harder than for a pure-C one
- If you "hide" `libstdc++` inside your shared library, and pass `C++` objects through the interface (e.g. a `std::string` or `std::map`), you can expect all kinds of ~impossible to debug issues due to ABI incompatibility between the "hidden" `libstdc++.a` and the external `libstdc++.so.6`.

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what I needed! Thank you ever so much!

Using the linker script has helped, now all those externally visible C++ symbols are hidden, as intended. Note this is fairly _abnormal_ programming. Related build options are: `-shared -fPIC -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -Wl,--version-script=libfoo.version`.